# Scope in jQuery(javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simplified my code for next example. So, please don't be wondered why I'm using ajax here.

```
 <!DOCTYPE>
<head>
     <style>.not { background:yellow; }</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".not").click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert('good');
        });
        $(".click").click(function(e){
            $.post('page2.php', 'q=1', function(data){
                $('body').append('<p class="click">Click here to add new paragraph <span class="not">[not here]</span></p>');
            }, "json");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="click">Click here to add new paragraph <span class="not">[not here]</span></p>
</body>
```

New rows don't make any alert for class=not! It is inexplicably for me :'(

Thanks for unswer!

Comment: Anyway, ajax aren't necessary for this example

Comment: section <span class="not">[not here]</span> of new rows, don't see
 $(".not").click(function(e){
            e.stopPropagation();
            alert('good');
        });

Comment: actually, the ajax IS necessary for this example.  it's what's not working.

Comment: Shouldn't `<!DOCTYPE>` be `<!DOCTYPE html>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming jQuery 1.7.x, use this:

```
$(document).on('click', ".not", function(e){
   alert('good');
}).on('click', ".click", function(e){
   if(!$(e.target).is('.not')) {
      $('body').append('<p class="click">Click here to add new paragraph <span class="not">[not here]</span></p>');
   }
});
```

The problem is, `.click` will only bind to elements that exist when it's called. Using `.on` the way I'm suggesting delegates the click handling to the `document` element. By passing a selector as the second argument, you tell jQuery to run the event handler only if the event target matches the selector.

Comment: @Pointy, you're right. I'm removing that line from the example, since I don't see any reason to be using it anyway.

Comment: The reason would be to prevent clicks inside the `span` from triggering the handler on the `".click"` element. With your current code, the events will still bubble up from the `[not here]`.

Comment: @amnotiam: Added a check based on `event.target` to deal with that. I guess I'm just answering this kind of question too fast.

Answer (score 1):

Put the `$(".not")...` part inside a function, such as `disableNot = function() {$(".not").click......}`. Then, after appending the new paragraph, call `disableNot()` to update the event handlers. (Also call `disableNot` immediately after defining it, so any `.not` elements already on the page are given their handlers.)

Answer (score 1):

In your `ready` event handler, you use `$('.not).click`.  `click` is an alias for `bind`, and `bind` only works on elements that are already in the DOM.

If you're using jQuery 1.7, you can use `on` instead, in its `delegate`-like form.